# Match multiple comma separated values against multiple comma separated values with multiple columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, match

In short: I have a table with pet products and a table with breeds of dogs and cats. To each pet product, I need to show all the breeds in which the characteristics of each meet.

Here is the detailed explanation:
With each Product Name in column J, I need to show in a comma separated manner (i.e. in one cell) all the Breed Names from Column A that mach in this way:

any of the comma separated values in Product Animal (column G) matches any of the comma separated values in Breed Animal (column B) AND any of the comma separated values in Product Size (column H) matches any of the comma separated values in Breed Size (column C) AND (any of the) Product Red (column I) matches Breed Red (column D).

If all of the above criteria are met, show the result in the column J. In the attached table I have shown what the result of the formula should be.

Can you please help me with the formula to do that? Ideally in Google Sheets, but excel is fine too.

Thank you

[Picture of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk82Q.png)

I tried `MATCH` and `SPLIT` function, which gave me partial success. But I am not able to move forward with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Can you test:*

```js
=map(G2:G,H2:H,I2:I,lambda(g,h,i,if(counta({g,h,i})<>3,,join(", ",ifna(filter(A:A,D:D=i,regexmatch(B:B,"\b"&substitute(g,", ","\b|\b")&"\b"),regexmatch(C:C,"\b"&substitute(h,", ","\b|\b")&"\b")))))))
```